# Drag Lock bug on MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook, touchpad

Even tho I untick Drag Lock in Settings, still when I double tap, move the window and release the finger from trackpad, window is still locked to trackpad, I have to tap again to unlock it. Anyone else met this problem? Running the latest Snow Leopard, 15" i5 MBP.

Comment: Still happens in Lion :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried to reproduce this and found that there is a small delay before the window stops moving with the mouse after you remove your finger from the trackpad, even when Drag Lock is disabled.

If you wait a little bit (say half a second or less) before moving your mouse again it should "unlock" from the window. At least that's what it does on my laptop.

I'm using an early jan-2008 MBP.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah you are right.. Do you know of any "hack" to decrease this delay?

Comment: I just found http://bettertouchtool.net/ ([via](http://yuji.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/mac-remove-touchpad-drag-delay-with-bettertouchtool-free/)) and it provides tap-to-drag without delay

Comment: Read about "without drag lock" and "with drag lock" functionality here https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/unac899/mac